# Position H1 below H2 on Page, but above it in Markup

Tags: css, xhtml, stylesheet, markup

I have some HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>css test</title>
<style type="text/css">
.box{width:100%;float:left;background:red}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Title To Appear Below Div on Page</h1>

<div class="box">
    <h2>This is a Heading 2</h2>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the Markup, the H1 is above the DIV.

However, I was wondering if it's possible to position this below the DIV when the user visits the web page.

Chances are the .box div will be a different height with every page refresh (it holds random text snippets).

Is it possible to place the H1 below the DIV on the page no matter the height of the DIV?

Thank you.

Comment: You have no way of changing the markup?  This would be much easier and cleaner to handle on the backend.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't simply rearrange your HTML?

Comment: In my full version I'm using XHTML and in the interests of semantic code, I would prefer to maintain my heading structure of H1 > H2 > H3 > H2 etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, guys, here's the solution :)

You need to use `display: table-caption` property on the header and `caption-side: bottom` on its container.

Here's the basic markup:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <h1>header</h1>
    <div class="box">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>​
```

and CSS:

```
h1 { 
    display: table-caption;
}
.wrap {
    display: table;
    caption-side: bottom;
}
.box {
    display: table-row;
}
```

And here's jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rjtyn/4/

Should work in ie8+ and other current browsers.

Comment: Many thanks, Spadar. I will take a look at this shortly and see how I implement it into my work.

Answer (score 0):

**If** the layout of the page is rigid and fixed you can use absolute positioning to do this. Leave enough white-space below "box" and absolutely-position the H1 tag. If the height of "box" is variable you could end up putting your H1 on top of other text. If it gets that bad you can always resort to JavaScript to calculate the position and do it dynamically.

All this is like scratching your left ear with your right hand.

Comment: Tell me about it. Client request. I explained it couldn't be done (as the box will vary in height) but thought I'd run it by the experts here :-) They never make it easy. ... thanks for looking anyway :-D